# Swift switch patterns matching with .some/.none

Tags: swift, switch-statement, option-type

```
var stream: DataStream? = nil
switch stream {
  case nil:
print("No data stream is configured.")
  case let x?:
print("The data stream has \(x.availableBytes) bytes available.")
}
```

Refrenced by [switch optional code](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/Optional.swift), the above content will call `public func ~= <T>(lhs: _OptionalNilComparisonType, rhs: T?) -> Bool` function. And there is another switch pattern in this function:

```
public func ~= <T>(lhs: _OptionalNilComparisonType, rhs: T?) -> Bool {
  switch rhs {
  case .some(_):
    return false
  case .none:
    return true
  }
}
```

My question is whitch function will be called by this pattern? There are two ~= overload functions in Range.swift & Policy.swift, does one of them will be called?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not totally clear to be but `~=` is the pattern match operator.

```
func ~=(pattern: ???, value: ???) -> Bool
```

By overriding it you are able to create your own pattern match for your custom types and use it into a `switch` (basically the switch call this operator).
There is a good article here https://appventure.me/2015/08/20/swift-pattern-matching-in-detail/ 
What are you seeing in `Range` and `Policy` are simply the custom overload of this operator to make it work with `Range` and `Policy` types as they did for optionals.

Comment: Thanks, does every switch pattern will call a _> overload finction? If so, whitch function will this pattern call ?

    switch rhs {
    case .some(_):
      return false
    case .none:
      return true
    }

Comment: I understand, not every switch pattern will call ~> overload function

Comment: If some types calls the `>` or `==` I guess that it will depends on the implementation of the `~=`